# Mysql changin username and password of a database

Tags: php, mysql

i am new to POD and php. i created a new database, and it's default username is "root" with an empty password. now how do i change that username and password?

Comment: Check out this article, it answers your question: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-root-password/

Answer (score 2):

You don't "change the username" of a database. You **GRANT** permissions to an account to use that database. See [GRANT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) docs.

Comment: i see.. so do i have to leave it that way? coz i am trying to make a database with username and password for my site.

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can use phpmyadmin for example to create a new user and give rights for him to work on the specific database.

[PMA Wiki](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/user_management)